# How to get last 4 digits?

Tags: javascript, sapui5

```xml
<Label text="{Kostl}"/ >
```

I need to get here the last 4 digits and not leading numbers.

[image]

Comment: to clarefy: you want to search for the last 4 didgits with the searchbar?

Comment: What are you trying to do? What do you mean by "Get"?

Comment: Btw.: Please avoid using `sap.m.Label` if it's not labeling anything. You can use `sap.m.Text` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [formatter method](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/0f8626ed7b7542ffaa44601828db20de) to do this **(recommended)**:

```
<Label text="{ path: 'Kostl', formatter: '.formatter.yourFormatterName' }" />
```

Or *(not recommended)* you can format it directly in your binding, like this:

```
<Label text="{= ${Kostl}.substring(4) }" />
```